# Why is the SharePoint date incorrect in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

In my VBA tool users are uploading their tasks on a daily basis to a SharePoint list. One of the data pieces is the tracking date, which is always the date of data submission (users cannot change it). I have a problem with one user - her date is uploaded as previous date (ex. data is sent on the 15th, in the tool, reports and SP list, it's displayed as 14th). Additionally, when she checks the data on her machine, it's displayed as 15th. What is strange, a unique id created for each item containing a date as a string, contains the correct date (eg. date is displayed as 14th, but the id contains 15082021).
Any ideas where this might come from? Office repair didn't help. Her manager sees the same dates as I do and all other data of other users is correct.
Below the snippet for record creation.

```
Sub AddRecord(rec As ADODB.Recordset, conn As ADODB.Connection, taskName As String, quantity As String, time As String, comment As String, _
            TaskBox As control, quantityBox As control, TimeBox As control, CommentsBox As control, t As Long, OutstandingBox As control, ByRef outstandingArray() As String)
uniqueID = VBA.UCase(VBA.Environ("username")) & VBA.Format(Now(), "ddmmyyhhmmss")
Dim ifOutstanding As String

If CheckOutstanding(OutstandingBox, uniqueID, outstandingArray) Then
    ifOutstanding = "Yes"
Else
    ifOutstanding = "No"
End If
With rec
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .source = "INSERT INTO tbl_tasks(Title,user_AID,user_name_last_name,user_location,user_region,user_team,task_name,task_count,task_time_in_minutes,comments,unique_id,outstanding_task,tracking_date)" & _
        "VALUES('1','" & AID & "','" & userName & "','" & userLocation & "','" & userRegion & "','" & userTeam & "','" & taskName & "'," & quantity & "," & time & ",'" & comment & "','" & uniqueID & "','" & ifOutstanding & "','" & Format(Date, "mmmm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss") & "')"
```

Comment: Are all users in the same timezone, and do they all have the same timezone settings?

Comment: I checked with her and didn't see any differences - she is located in the same time zone as we are and it's reflected on her laptop. Maybe there are some time settings I'm missing?

Comment: What data type is `tracking_date` ? `Format(Date, "mmmm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")` gives 'August/18/2021 00:00:00' .ie. first second of the day so maybe that is a factor.

Comment: It's a date type, excluding time. I think I've added the "hh:mm:ss" after having discovered the issue, but even with the date part only, it was still showing the previous day. The biggest mystery for me is the fact that she can still  see it as a correct one.

Comment: There maybe a setting on the users SharePoint profile https://www.codesharepoint.com/sharepoint-tutorial/sharepoint-regional-settings-and-datetime-issue

Comment: Thanks, I will follow up on that one and see if it helps.

Comment: If the link I gave doesn't work try https://sharepointmaven.com/sharepoint-time-zone/